# A non-deprecated exact equivalent of Date(String s) in Java?

Tags: java, date

I have old code that uses `new Date(dateString)` to parse a date string. Compiling the code produces the deprecation warning *`Date(java.lang.String) in java.util.Date has been deprecated`*.

The javadoc unhelpfully advises me to use `DateFormat.parse()`, even though the `DateFormat` class does not have a static `parse` method.

Now, I know how to use `SimpleDateFormat`, but I want to make sure I'm getting the **exact same behaviour** of the deperecated `Date` constructor.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here's my guess (I posted as community wiki so you can vote up if I'm right):

```
Date parsed;
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format =
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    parsed = format.parse(dateString);
}
catch(ParseException pe) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(pe);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much how I'd do it if I wanted to get exactly the same behaviour.  The reason why DateFormat.getInstance() is better is it returns the appropriate formatter for the current locale.

Comment: Please, pretty please never, ever do a "new IllegalgArgumentException()" :O . At the very least chain the original exception (new IllegalArgumentException(pe)).

Comment: I had to use "new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);" to make this work - Just in case someone else is having problems.

Comment: FYI, these terrible date-time classes were supplanted a few years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 8):

SimpleDateFormat is the way to go. Can I point out, however, that you may feel compelled to define one SimpleDateFormat instance and build Date objects using this. If you do, beware that SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe and you may be exposing yourself to some potentially hard-to-debug issues!

I'd recommend taking this opportunity to look at [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is a much better thought-out (and thread-safe) API. It forms the basis of JSR-310, which is the new proposed Java Date API.

I understand this is a bit more work. However it's probably worthwhile given that you're having to refactor code at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at source of the Date.parse(String s) method that Nicolas mentions, you'll see that it will be difficult or impossible to construct a date format that **exactly** reproduces the behavior.

If you just want to eliminate the warning, you could put `@SuppressWarnings({“deprecation”})` outside the method calling the Date(String) constructor.

If you really want to ensure future access to this behavior with future JREs, you might be able to just extract the method from the JDK sources and put it into your own sources.  This would require a careful read of the source code licenses and consideration of their application to your specific project, and might not be permissible at all.

Answer (score 2):

DateFormat has static methods that return DateFormat instances. I don't know which one (if any) has the same behavior as `Date(String s)` but here you go:

```
DateFormat.getInstance()
DateFormat.getDateInstance()
DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer (before further investigation) is: no, it is not equivalent. the Date(String toParse) constructor is equivalent to the parse method of the class Date (which is also deprecated)... And the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String)) of this method claims:

> Note that this is slightly different from the interpretation of years less than 100 that is used in SimpleDateFormat.

If it is the only change, I guess you can go on this way.

Answer (score 2):

To parse a date time string in ISO format you should use the DateFormat like this:

`java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(dt);`

With SimpleDateFormat you need to know the format.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22980954)

Comment: This differs from the previous answers because it is a simple "one-line" answer that is tthe equivalent function of the one line in the original question. 

val dateObject = DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse("string")

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.format( 
    input , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , 
        Locale.ENGLISH 
    ) 
)
```

## java.time

The terrible `Date` and `DateFormat` classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [constructor you reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) is actually calls on the static method [`Date.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String)). As that documentation explains, that method takes a variety of formats. There is single point for the same behavior in *java.time*. However, I would doubt your app is encountering all those various format syntaxes simultaneously.

I suggest you look at the specific formats used by your actual data. Then craft a collection of `DateTimeFormatter` objects to match. Note that unlike the legacy classes, the *java.time* classes are entirely [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). So you can keep one set of formatters around for use repeatedly throughout your app and across threads.

For the formatting pattern shown in the accepted Answer, here is the equivalent in *java.time* using the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Note that you should explicitly state your desired/expected locale rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default locale.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , Locale.ENGLISH ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.format( input , f ) ;
```

You should avoid using the legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` wherever possible. But if you must have a `Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. Look to new conversions methods added to the old classes.

The misnamed [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) represents a moment in UTC. Its modern equivalent
 is the [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class. We can extract an `Instant` from our `ZonedDateTime`. Then convert to a `Date`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;        // Adjust from time zone to UTC.
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;  // Convert from modern class `Instant` to legacy class `Date`.
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;                                        // Convert from legacy class `Date` to modern class `Instant`. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;  // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).